# VBA for loop with two input variables returning "invalid next control variable reference" error

Tags: excel, vba

I receive a  "invalid next control variable reference" error when i try to run this VBA code.

Here's my VBA code:

```
Sub forecast()

Dim dvCell As Range
Dim inputRange As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim dvcell2 As Range
Dim inputRange2 As Range
Dim c2 As Range

'Which cell has data validation
Set dvCell = Worksheets("Cost Model").Range("B1")
'Determine where validation comes from
Set inputRange = Evaluate(dvCell.Validation.Formula1)

'Which cell has data validation (market segment)
Set dvcell2 = Worksheets("Cost Curve").Range("B2")
'Determine where validation comes from (market segment)
Set inputRange2 = Evaluate(dvcell2.Validation.Formula1)



'Begin our loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each c In inputRange
    For Each c2 In inputRange2
        dvCell = c.Value
        dvcell2 = c2.Value
    
    
        Worksheets("Price Forecast").Columns("B:B").EntireColumn.Insert
        Worksheets("Price Forecast").Range("B1:B14").Value = Worksheets("Cost Curve").Range("B1:B14").Value
    
    Next c
Next c2

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Any idea why I am experiencing this error?

Comment: `Next c` needs to be before `Next c2` you need to close the inner loop first! Just switch them.

Answer (score 1):

```
Next c
Next c2
```

in inverted

```
Next c2
Next c
```

could work

Comment: *"could work"* and removes the mentioned error for sure.